# JFreeChart interactive chart editing handling ChartMouseEvent

Tags: java, mouseevent, jfreechart, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to intercept ChartMouseEvent in order to modify an XYSeries of a JFreeChart object created with ChartFactory.createXYLineChart method (and displayed using a JDialog).

[image: XYLineChart]

I retrieve successfully the coordinate of the mouse event this way:

```
public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent arg0) {
    int x = arg0.getTrigger().getX();
        int y = arg0.getTrigger().getY();
```

The origin of the coordinate system (0,0) is located at the red square in the picture.
Now, I would like to calculate in which interval is the mouse in. In order to do this I need:

1. the top-left coordinate of the grey chart (green square)
2. height and width of the grey chart

How can I get this values?

A note: I'm a JFreeChart newbie. If I'm doing this wrong, and there is a better way to do achive these goals, please put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you rendering the plot via `ChartPanel`?

If so, take a look at `ChartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getDataArea()`.  This should return a `Rectangle2D` that is easy to work with.