# JFreeChart interactive chart editing: transforming mouse coordinates into series values

Tags: java, mouseevent, jfreechart, coordinate-systems

I have an XYLineChart built with JFreeChart. I need, given that chart and a ChartMouseEvent, retrieve the X value of the displayde series closest to the point where the mouse has been clicked.

Thanks to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189445/jfreechart-interactive-chart-editing-handling-chartmouseevent) I have been able to retrieve the offset of the grey chart (the coordinates of the green point in the image) and its dimension with the following method:

```
Rectangle2D greyChartArea = chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getDataArea();
```

I also know the max X values of the displayed serie:

```
double maxXValue = seriesCollection.getDomainUpperBound(true); //where seriesCollection is an XYSeriesCollection object
```

[image: XYLineChart]

Now the problem is that for converting a mouse coordinate (Point) into a corresponding value in the chart, I need to know at how many units (double) correspond a pixel on the screen.
Unfortunately there is a gap between the maximum X value (60 in this case) and the grey chart width (look at the big blue line), so I can't achieve a perfect conversion.

Then I have two questions:

1. How to calculate exactly the gap in pixel between the last displayed x value and the whole grey chart ? ( big blue line length)
2. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any simpler way to achieve this goals, possibly avoiding all this calculus? I'm a JFreeChart newbie and the documentation of that library isn't enough, so maybe I'm missing some features that could help me.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post +1

Comment: @mKorbel: have you ever used JFreeChart? Have you got any idea?

Comment: no never, I think that this is only trashgod area here(on this forum), as I know sorry man...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  final XYPlot plot = getChart().getXYPlot();
  final ValueAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
  final ValueAxis rangeAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
  final Rectangle2D plotRectangle = SWTUtils.toAwtRectangle(getScreenDataArea());
  final double chartX = domainAxis.java2DToValue(relativeX, plotRectangle, plot.getDomainAxisEdge());
  final double chartY = rangeAxis.java2DToValue(relativeY, plotRectangle, plot.getRangeAxisEdge());
```

We have used this to get the data coordinates from the mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

Recalling this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071057/how-do-i-rotate-tick-mark-labels-on-the-domain-of-a-number-axis-in-jfreechart/7073428#7073428), you can obtain model coordinates from the cross-hair values in a [`ChartProgressListener`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/event/ChartProgressListener.html). The cross-hairs don't have to be visible.

```
chartPanel.getChart().addProgressListener(new ChartProgressListener() {

    @Override
    public void chartProgress(ChartProgressEvent e) {
        XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) chartPanel.getChart().getPlot();
        System.out.println(e.getType()
            + ": " + xyPlot.getDomainCrosshairValue()
            + ", " + xyPlot.getRangeCrosshairValue());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [JFreeChart get mouse coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512112/jfreechart-get-mouse-coordinates). If you know the coordinate, you can take the x and y-coordinates from your plot, and get the corresponding values from the axises:

```
JFreeChart chart = yourChart;
Rectangle2D greyChartArea = chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getDataArea();
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();

double valueX = ((NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis()).java2DToValue(chartY,plot.getRangeAxisEdge();
double valueY = ((NumberAxis) plot.getDomainAxis()).java2DToValue(chartX,plot.getDomainAxisEdge();
```

That should do it.

Comment: +1 : thanks to you too. I set Kathir's answer as correct because you have inverted valueX with valueY. Nothing personal but I had to choose an answer. Thanks again, both of you have been very helpful!

Comment: What version of JFreeChart are you running?