# Setting Range for X,Y Axis-JfreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Any suggestions over how to set Range for X-Axis and Y-Axis.

My "X-Axis" Range is from "0.00 to 1.00" with difference of "0.05". I mean 0.00 0.05 0.10 0.15.....0.90 0.95 1.00

My "Y-Axis" Range is from "0.0 to 1.0" with difference of "0.1". I mean 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4.........0.9 1.0

I tried doing this Way, but it's not reflecting on the Graph; I don't know how to apply it to  `ChartFactory.createScatterPlot()`.

```
final NumberAxis domainAxis = new NumberAxis("X-Axis");
domainAxis.setRange(0.00,1.00);
domainAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.1));
final NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis("Y-Axis");
rangeAxis.setRange(0.0,1.0);
rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.05));

public  JPanel createDemoPanel() {
    XYDataset dataset1 = samplexydataset2();
    JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot("Scatter Plot Demo",
        "X", "Y",dataset1, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
}
```

Any help regarding this would be great.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'm guessing your new `NumberAxis` instances aren't being used by the plot; it may be easier to use the existing ones from the factory.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnit;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231824
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205742
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208657
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071057
 */
public class ScatterAdd extends JFrame {

    private static final int N = 8;
    private static final String title = "Scatter Add Demo";
    private static final Random rand = new Random();
    private XYSeries added = new XYSeries("Added");

    public ScatterAdd(String s) {
        super(s);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = createDemoPanel();
        this.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel control = new JPanel();
        control.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    added.add(rand.nextDouble(), rand.nextDouble());
                }
            }
        }));
        this.add(control, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private ChartPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
            title, "X", "Y", createSampleData(),
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
        xyPlot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        xyPlot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);
        XYItemRenderer renderer = xyPlot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
        NumberAxis domain = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setRange(0.00, 1.00);
        domain.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.1));
        domain.setVerticalTickLabels(true);
        NumberAxis range = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setRange(0.0, 1.0);
        range.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.1));
        return new ChartPanel(jfreechart);
    }

    private XYDataset createSampleData() {
        XYSeriesCollection xySeriesCollection = new XYSeriesCollection();
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Random");
        for (int i = 0; i < N * N; i++) {
            double x = rand.nextDouble();
            double y = rand.nextDouble();
            series.add(x, y);
        }
        xySeriesCollection.addSeries(series);
        xySeriesCollection.addSeries(added);
        return xySeriesCollection;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ScatterAdd demo = new ScatterAdd(title);
                demo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                demo.pack();
                demo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                demo.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome; you might also examine [`JFreeChart.createScatterPlot()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1464) itself.

Comment: how can i change the size of blue markers? I would like to make blue markers bigger but keep the size of red ones unchanged

Comment: Strange, negative range doesn't work. Ie -5.00 to 5.00. Only values >=0 will be plotted.

Comment: @BakedInhalf: The example adds data in the range `[0,1)`; try adding negative values to see the difference.

Comment: @trashgod I did, but tried with a XYPLOT and StandardXYItemRenderer. I have two y-axis (left in range 60-90) and right in -200 to 200. Everything works fine except any negative number on the "right" axis will be truncated, not plotted. Strange issue, but maybe another question..

Comment: @BakedInhalf: Looks OK [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13362809/230513).

Answer (score 17):

Unless the code that you pasted is incomplete, it looks like your problem is that you didn't associate the NumberAxis objects that you created with your plot.

Instead of creating new NumberAxis objects manually, try getting the default ValueAxis objects that are associated with your plot, then modifying their properties:

```
XYPlot xyPlot = jfreechart.getXYPlot();
ValueAxis domainAxis = xyPlot.getDomainAxis();
ValueAxis rangeAxis = xyPlot.getRangeAxis();

domainAxis.setRange(0.0, 1.0);
domainAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.1));
rangeAxis.setRange(0.0, 1.0);
rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.05));
```