# dynamically change Y axis range in Jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a time series data which I can draw using jfreechart. the issue is, as new data comes in, the chart will change based on the new dataset. I used,

chart.fireChartChanged();
chartPanel.repaint();

the issue is, some data may be out of the current range of Y axis, I'm wondering how can the axis range be changed according to the maximum value in the timeseries I had so far? thanks!

Comment: If this is a duplicate account, you can request a [merge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste/73801#73801) of your other account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used `chart.fireChartChanged(); chartPanel.repaint();`… but the chart still has the old range after repaint.

This all seems unnecessarily complicated: axis ranging and notification should be automatic. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205742/adding-points-to-xyseries-dynamically-with-jfreechart/7208723#7208723), the range changes as outliers accumulate, because [`add()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html#add%28double,%20double%29) "sends a `SeriesChangeEvent` to all registered listeners." In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231824/setting-range-for-x-y-axis-jfreechart/7232680#7232680), the range is fixed, but the same notification happens.

As we can't guess how your program fails in this regard, it may help to provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem(s) you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Range class](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/Range.html) .

There are many methods like

```
combine(Range range1, Range range2)
          Creates a new range by combining two existing ranges.

expandToInclude(Range range, double value)
      Returns a range that includes all the values in the specified range AND the specified value.

shift(Range base, double delta, boolean allowZeroCrossing)
          Shifts the range by the specified amount.
```

You can use any depending upon your requirements

you might even have to add following [based on your comments]

```
timeaxis.setAutoRange(true);
timeaxis.setFixedAutoRange(1000.0);
```

Comment: thanks for the response. when I create the plot, i used a Range to set the axis. e.g. yRange = new Range() and pass it to the axis. later when the chart is updated on the new data, I changed yRange but the chart still has the old range after repaint. or do I need to retrieve it from the chart object directly?