# JFreeChart and Y-axis Units

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a StackedXYAreaChart that looks like the following:

[image]

How do I format the Y-axis units so that they are evenly spaced out and are displayed at certain intervals? For example, instead of displaying units in increments of 1 (e.g. `0, 1, 2, 3, ... 100`), I want to display units in increments of 10 or 25 (e.g., `0, 25, 50, 75, 100`). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to my own question. I'm using a `CustomTickUnit` that formats numbers and adds units to the suffix, e.g. `1000000` becomes `1 GB`.

I set up my tick units with the following code, which spaced them out evenly and formatted them appropriately so that they are very readable:

```
public void setupRangeAxis(NumberAxis rangeAxis) {
  final TickUnits standardUnits = new TickUnits();
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(1));
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(10));
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(100));
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(1000)); // Kilo
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(10000));
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(100000));
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(1000000)); // Mega
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(10000000));
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(100000000));
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(1000000000)); // Giga
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(10000000000L));
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(100000000000L));
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(1000000000000L)); // Tera
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(10000000000000L));
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(100000000000000L));
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(1000000000000000L)); // Peta
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(10000000000000000L));
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(100000000000000000L));
  standardUnits.add(new CustomTickUnit(1000000000000000000L)); // Exa
  rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(standardUnits);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();

NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();

rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(300));
```

Comment: Could you provide a little explanation for your answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a [`NumberAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html), set the tick unit to 25. There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231824/setting-range-for-x-y-axis-jfreechart/7232680#7232680).

```
axis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(25));
```