# Cannot display properlly axis and tooltip on jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have problem on the Axis and the Tooltip display on JFreeChart they don't display all the values, I am trying to display the bytes based on daily use, here is an image to show exactly my problem:
[image]

There are missing some values and on the tallest red bar it doesn't show me the bytes on the tooltip. Here is my code:

```
final JFreeChart chart = createTrafficChart();
    chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, true, true, true, true, true);       
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(750, 367));              
    a.gridx = 0;
    a.gridy = 3;
    jpContainer.add(chartPanel, a);

private JFreeChart createTrafficChart() {

    // create plot ...
    final IntervalXYDataset data1 = createDatasetDownload();
    XYBarRenderer t= new XYBarRenderer(0.20);
    t.setShadowVisible(false);
    final XYItemRenderer renderer1 = t;
    renderer1.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new MyTrafficToolTipGenerator());
    final DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis("Date");
    domainAxis.setTickMarkPosition(DateTickMarkPosition.MIDDLE);
    final NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis("Bytes");
    setupRangeAxis(rangeAxis);
    final XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(data1, domainAxis, rangeAxis, renderer1);

    // add a second dataset and renderer...
    final XYDataset data2 = createDatasetUpload();
    final XYItemRenderer renderer2 = new StandardXYItemRenderer();
    renderer2.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new MyTrafficToolTipGenerator());
    plot.setDataset(1, data2);
    plot.setRenderer(1, renderer2);        
    plot.setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);

    return new JFreeChart("Traffic", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);

}
```

And this code:

```
public void setupRangeAxis(NumberAxis rangeAxis) {
      final TickUnits standardUnits = new TickUnits();
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(1));
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(10));
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(100));
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(1024)); // Kilo
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(10000));
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(100000));
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(1024*1024)); // Mega
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(10000000));
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(100000000));
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(1024*1024*1024)); // Giga
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(10000000000L));
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(100000000000L));
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(1024*1024*1024*1024)); // Tera
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(10000000000000L));
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(100000000000000L));
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(1000000000000000L)); // Peta
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(10000000000000000L));
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(100000000000000000L));
      standardUnits.add(new MyNumberTickUnit(1000000000000000000L)); // Exa
      rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(standardUnits);
    }
```

Which i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853145/jfreechart-and-y-axis-units) .
I also have this code:

```
public class MyNumberTickUnit extends NumberTickUnit{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4281451255133640119L;

public MyNumberTickUnit(double size) {
    super(size);

}

public String valueToString(double value){  
    return StringFormat.formatTheTraffic(value);
}
```

}

```
public class StringFormat {
public static String formatTheTraffic(double input) {
        String result = "";

        if (input < KILO_BYTES) {
            result = input + " Byte";
        } else if ((input < MEGA_BYTES) && (input >= KILO_BYTES)) {
            result = new DecimalFormat("##.#").format(input / KILO_BYTES) + " KB";
        } else if ((input < GIGA_BYTES) && (input >= MEGA_BYTES)) {
            result = new DecimalFormat("##.#").format(input / MEGA_BYTES) + " MB";
        } else if ((input < TERA_BYTES) && (input >= GIGA_BYTES)) {
            result = new DecimalFormat("##.#").format(input / GIGA_BYTES) + " GB";
        }
        return result;
    }
    }
```

Thanks for your attention and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. It was inside the formatTheTraffic method! I change it and works properly now!