# JFreeChart how to draw ordered lines

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am currently using JFreeChart scatter graph to display a number of points. When I use the scatter graph to draw lines it draws them in the wrong order for example: the ordered list (2,3),(2,5),(3,4) is the desired order to be printed. JFreeChart takes this and draws the line in this order (2,5),(2,3),(3,4). Is there an alternative chart type I could use that could display this differently or is there a way I can override their default ordering system? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [`XYSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html) is typically used to create a scatter plot's data set. It includes constructors that exert control over the sorting. There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7232680/230513).

Answer (score 0):

create XYSeries with autoSort flag set to false