# Jfree chart XY plot : how can we set the space between horizontal lines to 0.3 and vertical lines to 0.4?

Tags: jfreechart

Hi I am trying to set the space between horizontal grid lines of y axis to 0.3 and vertical  grid lines of x axis to 0.4 in XY Plot.

I have tried setting the width and margins but,I see no difference in horizontal and vertical grid lines of xy plot.

please can u let me know how can we achieve it.

thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

The grid line spacing follows `TickUnit` interval of the corresponding axis. You can change the values as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7232680/230513) and below.

```
domain.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.4));
range.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.3));
```