# jaspersoft jfreechart range or y axis is derived incorrectly

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart

I am using jasper reports with charting. The chart generally works with a wide variety of values. 
In one case the values are either 1.011 or 1.01 for the range or Y axis. That is, the user tries to generate a chart and some of the values are 1.011 and some are 1.01.
The challenge is, when generating a chart with these values, the chart is scaled incorrectly on the range or Y axis. The labels range from 1.000 to 1.010 with increments of .001. As the top of the chart is 1.010, the values 1.011 fall off the top of the chart and don't appear on the chart.
Can anybody explain how the range or Y axis is derived beyond stating that the axis is derived from the data. And why, in this case, is the axis derived
incorrectly?
Is there a way to configure the chart to display the range or Y axis more correctly?
I edit a jrxml file. I do not use iReports or java api.
Thanks for all of your assistance and good ideas

Comment: Why not manually set min and max values on the Y-axis?

Comment: How is the best way to set the axis manually?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231824/setting-range-for-x-y-axis-jfreechart

Comment: Is there a way to set the values for the axis without using the java API? I am trying to set the axis using jasper reports, by editing params in the jrxml file