# Drawing real-time graphics in cartesian coordinates with GUI in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I'm searching a way to draw dots in Cartesian coordinates in real-time when entering a value to a `JTable`. When I enter `2` to first column and `3` to second columns, without clicking a button, the point should be at (2,3) in coordinates.  What are some ways to do this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a scatter plot that reflects the current entries in a two column `JTable`. One approach would be to add a `TableModelListener` to your `JTable`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513). In your implementation of `tableChanged()`, update the plot. Using [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart), you would update the `XYSeries` contained in an `XYSeriesCollection` used to create a scatter plot, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7232680/230513). The listening chart will update itself in response. In the brute force approach, you could `clear()` the series and iterate through the table's `TableModel`, adding current values to the series as you go. Alternatively, identify the row that changed and `update()` the corresponding entry in the series.

Starting from the first example cited, you could simply replace the `JList` on the right with the `ChartPanel` used in the second example. The `TableModelListener` obviates the need for a button to generate the update.

[image]
[image]