# JFreechart - vertical X-axis labels on an XYChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have an XYLineChart, where the labels on the X axis are written horizontally.  I would like to be able to write them vertically (descending).

I can already do this for BarCharts:

```
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
final CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.DOWN_90);
```

but an XYChart returns an XYPlot, rather than a CategoryPlot, and the getDomainAxis() of an XYPlot returns a ValueAxis, not a CategoryAxis. ValueAxis lets me call

```
setVerticalTickLabels(true);
```

which is almost there!  But it draws them ascending, rather than descending.  Any way around this?

Thanks,

Edit: I need the domain axis to stay at the bottom of the chart.  Hadn't considered it being any other way when making the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, this didn't seem to be possible, so I had to add the functionality to the jfreechart source myself.

Answer (score 1):

[`ValueAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html) does this automatically in [`drawTickMarksAndLabels()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#line.674) for an axis on the `RectangleEdge.TOP` edge:

```
xyPlot.setDomainAxisLocation(AxisLocation.TOP_OR_LEFT);
```

[image]

Example based on a variation of [`ScatterAdd`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8056418/230513).

Comment: Thanks.  I need the labels on the bottom, rather than the top, though.  I've had to modify the source to achieve this.