# How to set the range for Y-Axis using JfreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to create line chart with XYlinechart but i have a problem with create a Y-axis range. My "Y-Axis" range is start with 0  80  85  90  95  100

This is my code:

```
// for x-axis
    final NumberAxis domainAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
    domainAxis.setRange(0, 90); 
    domainAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(10)); 
    domainAxis.setVerticalTickLabels(true); 
// for y-axis
    final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis(); 
    rangeAxis.setRange(0, 100); 
    rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(......)); 

    return chart;
```

Please guide me with your valuable suggestions. 
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what do you mean by difference(20)? the NumberTickUnit?

Comment: yes,difference(20) is the NumberTickUnit, but i want the NumberTickUnit is 5 but at my rang should start at 0,80,85,90,95,100.Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(0.5))` works as expected in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8056418/230513), illustrated below. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

[image: image]]

Comment: Hello, sir. I want to create a line chart, but i don't know how i create Y-axis range that have values from 0 and then jump to 80 85 90 95 100. Can you advince me more?

Comment: Yes, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.