# How do I change a JFreeChart's size

Tags: java, swing, layout, jfreechart, sizing

I've added a `JFreeChart` to a `JPanel` (using a `BorderLayout`), and it's *huge*. Is there something I can do to make it smaller?

```
public void generateChart()
{
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

    //set the values of the chart
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        dataset.setValue(income_array[i], "Income",
            Double.toString(percent_array[i]));
    }

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
        "Required Annual Income for a Variety of Interest Rates",
        "Percent", "Income", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
        false,true, false);
    ChartPanel cp = new ChartPanel(chart);

    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.black); 
    CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot(); 
    p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.blue); 

    //cp.setMaximumDrawHeight(5);
    //cp.setMaximumDrawWidth(5);
    //cp.setZoomOutFactor(.1);
    JPanel graph = new JPanel();
    graph.add(cp);
    middle.add(graph, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you create your [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html), you have several options that affect the result:

1. Accept the `DEFAULT_WIDTH` and `DEFAULT_HEIGHT`: 680 x 420.
2. Specify the preferred `width` and `height` in the constructor.
3. Invoke `setPreferredSize()` explicitly if [appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).
4. Override `getPreferredSize()` to calculate the size dynamically.

   ```
   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
       // given some values of w & h
       return new Dimension(w, h);
   }
   ```
5. Choose the [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) of the container to which the `ChartPanel` will be added. Note that  the default layout of `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`, while that of `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`. As a concrete example, [`ThermometerDemo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7602126/230513) uses both preferred values in the constructor and a `GridLayout` for the container to allow dynamic resizing.

[image]

Comment: If appropriate? From what I see in the mostly upvoted (and accepted) answer, it's never appropriate ;)

Comment: ok, I see what you did here. consider linking to your answer then, not to the question then

Comment: Thanks for reading and commenting. If only it were so simple! I'd say it's _occasionally_ appropriate, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7229662/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665828/230513).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answer "4" of @trashgod, I had the same problem and managed to solve it like this:
(1) create a custom class which extends JPanel
(2) get the size somehow, that you would like to pass to your chart
(3) create a method which returns a "ChartPanel" object like this:

```
ChartPanel chart() {
    //... custom code here
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(title, pieDataset, false, false, false );`enter code here`
    // Now: this is the trick to manage setting the size of a chart into a panel!:
    return new ChartPanel(chart) { 
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }
    };
}
```

I prepared a SSCCE to let you know how it works:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

public class MyPieChart extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        example1();
        example2();
        example3();
    }

    public static void example1() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(50, 80, 100, 100);
        MyPieChart piePanel = new MyPieChart("Example 1", dataset(), panel);
        panel.add(piePanel);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(null); 
        frame.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 300);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void example2() {
        MyPieChart piePanel = new MyPieChart("Example 2", dataset(), 30, 50, 100, 100);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(null); 
        frame.setBounds(210, 10, 200, 300);
        frame.add(piePanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void example3() {
        MyPieChart piePanel = new MyPieChart("Example 3", dataset(), 100, 100);
        piePanel.setLocation(0,0);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(null); 
        frame.setBounds(410, 10, 200, 300);
        frame.add(piePanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataset() {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataset = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        dataset.add(row( "Tom", "LoggedIn", "Spain" ));
        dataset.add(row( "Jerry", "LoggedOut", "England" ));
        dataset.add(row( "Gooffy", "LoggedOut", "France" ));
        return dataset;
    }

    static ArrayList<String> row(String name, String actualState, String country) {
        ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
        row.add(name); row.add(actualState); row.add(country); 
        return row;
    }

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataset;
    DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset(); 
    int width, height, posX, posY;
    int colState = 1;
    String title;
    String LoggedIn = "LoggedIn";
    String LoggedOut = "LoggedOut";

    public MyPieChart(String title, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataset, int...args) {

        if(args.length==2) {
            this.width = args[0];
            this.height = args[1];
            this.setSize(width, height);
        }
        else if(args.length==4) {
            this.posX = args[0];
            this.posY = args[1];
            this.width = args[2];
            this.height = args[3];
            this.setBounds(posX, posY, width, height);
        }
        else {
            System.err.println("Error: wrong number of size/position arguments");
            return;
        }

        this.title = title;
        this.dataset = dataset;
        this.add(chart());
    }

    public MyPieChart(String title, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataset, JPanel panel) {
        this.title = title;
        this.dataset = dataset;
        this.width = panel.getWidth();
        this.height = panel.getHeight();
        this.setBounds(panel.getBounds());
        this.add(chart());
    }

    ChartPanel chart() {

        int totalLoggedIn = 0;
        int totalLoggedOut = 0;

        for(ArrayList<String> user : dataset) {
            if(user.get(colState).equals(LoggedIn)) totalLoggedIn++;
            else totalLoggedOut++;
        }
        pieDataset.clear();
        pieDataset.setValue(LoggedIn +": "+ totalLoggedIn, totalLoggedIn);
        pieDataset.setValue(LoggedOut +": "+ totalLoggedOut, totalLoggedOut);

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(title, pieDataset, false, false, false );

        return new ChartPanel(chart) { // this is the trick to manage setting the size of a chart into a panel!
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(width, height);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I really hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with my pie chart being too big with BorderLayout too. I ended up solving my problem by converting the chart to an image instead.

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

**Code**

```
 private PieDataset updateCSFDataSet(){
        DefaultPieDataset dataSet = new DefaultPieDataset();
            dataSet.setValue("Clear(" + clearCount + ")" , clearCount);
            dataSet.setValue("Smoky(" + smokyCount + ")", smokyCount);
            dataSet.setValue("Foggy(" + foggyCount + ")", foggyCount);
            dataSet.setValue("Skipped(" + skipCount + ")", skipCount);
            dataSet.setValue("Unlabeled(" + unlabeledCount + ")", unlabeledCount);
        return dataSet;
    }

    private ImageIcon createChart(String title, PieDataset dataSet){
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
                title,
                dataSet,
                true,
                false,
                false
        );

        PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setLabelFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        plot.setNoDataMessage("No data available");
        plot.setCircular(true);
        plot.setIgnoreZeroValues(true);
        plot.setLabelGap(0.02);

        return new ImageIcon(chart.createBufferedImage(400,300));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the size of the Panel your chart is in.

You might need to set both JPanel middle and ChartPanel cp