# How to add ChartPanel to Jpanel in java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jfreechart

I have parent panel and child panel. child parent exists on parent panel. Both are Jpanels of different size. Now i want to show a ChartPanel on the child panel. I have tried various ways of displaying it but unsucessfull. Please suggest some way of adding chartpanel to Jpanel.

sorry i couldnt paste the code. I have also tried various ways suggested in stackoverflow Q&A, but in vain.

Comment: Not sure what exactly your problem is. I worked with jfreechart in the past. I have created it with JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(...);
ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart); ChartPanel is of type JPanel. Probably you must set layout of your child panel?

Comment: Instead of pasting the code, please edit your question to include a _new_ [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your approach.

Comment: @ka3ak what kind of parameters are need to be set in layout manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem has nothing to do with JFreeChart. Probably the code below helps you to start:

```
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel();
                parentPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("parent panel"));

                JPanel childPanel = new JPanel();
                childPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("child panel"));
                // Add a button to the child panel
                childPanel.add(new JButton("button"));
                // In the instruction below you have to create and add your ChartPanel
                childPanel.add(yourChartPanel);
                parentPanel.add(childPanel);

                frame.add(parentPanel);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `ChartPanel` establishes a preferred size and [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) relies on the preferred size, let a `newPanel` extend `Box` using the desired orientation and `add()` both `child` and `chartPanel` to `newPanel`.

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513) and the source of [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#line.246).