# jfreechart chartpanel auto resize show all zoomed chart

Tags: java, swing, zooming, jscrollpane, jfreechart

[image]

I created a jfrechart as the first pic. After having zoomed it with mouse wheel, It showed as the second pic. How can I resize ChartPanel so that it can show all the zoomed chart?

I put the ChartPanel in a JScrollPane and updated its preferred size in its mouseWheelMoved event as follows. It did not work as I expected. It didn't show the whole chart and the font size of axises were also enlarged to unsuitable size.

```
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {

            double factor = _chartPanel.getZoomInFactor();
            Dimension dim = _chartPanel.getPreferredSize();
            dim.width =(int)( dim.width*(1.0+factor)+1);
            _chartPanel.setDomainZoomable(false);
            _chartPanel.setPreferredSize(dim);;
            _chartPanel.revalidate();
            _chartPanel.setDomainZoomable(true);

        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [*Minimal, Complete, Valid Example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to usefully mix zooming and scrolling. Absent a [*Minimal, Complete, Valid Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),

- You can restore the original zoom state using `restoreAutoBounds()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513).
- Among the several ways to control chart size, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513), overriding `getPreferredSize()` seems like the best approach for the reasons mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).
- Also consider extending `ChartPanel` to implement the `Scrollable` interface, as discussed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollable).