# JFreechart two bar charts in one image but not superimposed

Tags: image, charts, plot, jfreechart

i would like to generate two bar charts into 2 different plots. Why not something like this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartMultiplePieChartDemo1.htm but for bar chart instead of pie one.

I'm using [ServletUtilities.saveChartAsPng()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/servlet/ServletUtilities.html#saveChartAsPNG-org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart-int-int-javax.servlet.http.HttpSession-) which takes as (first) argument the JFreeChart object, but i don't see how to create my JFreeChart object which must hold 2 bar charts / 2 plots (and a common legend, but this is not my main problem currently)

I googled a lot, but i did not find what i'm still looking for.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513), you can add an arbitrary number of `ChartPanel` instances to an enclosing panel. Override the panel's `getPreferredSize()` method, use a suitable layout and `pack()` the enclosing `Window`. Optionally, suppress the legend in all but one chart.