# Increase width of label container

Tags: jfreechart

I have a label which breaks up as the container in which it is written (blue box) is quite small. As you can see in the screenshot, the word centuries is spread across 2 lines. I could not find any method which could increase the container and display the word correctly.
Is it possible to increase the width without impacting the size of the pie chart?

[chart http://uploadpie.com/ORbZv](http://uploadpie.com/ORbZv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label space is defined as a percentage of the entire canvas. If you give the label more space, you will end up with a smaller pie.

You can manipulate the percentages using these methods:

```
piePlot.setLabelGap(0);
piePlot.setInteriorGap(0.0);
piePlot.setMaximumLabelWidth(0.30);
```

Comment: @Nilesh Naik: Also consider [these ways](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513) to affect the chart size.

Comment: Thanks @trashgod this info was helpful!