# JFreeChart Ring Chart : Only Legends section is displaying but Ring Chart is not displaying

Tags: pdf, jfreechart

Can anyone help me out Why Only Legends section is displaying but Ring Chart is not displaying IF the data set has more data records say > 50. I have stuck with it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the data, that may be too many values to display usefully. You can try the static method [`DatasetUtilities.createConsolidatedPieDataset()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/DatasetUtilities.html) to derive a dataset that is "modified by aggregating all the low value items (those whose value is lower than the `percentThreshold`) into a single item with the key "Other".

> Is there any other way to increase entire chart size?

I'd override `getPreferredSize()` in `ChartPanel` like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/261156).

Comment: Thanks for reply.. But the requirement is to display all the slices with corresponding name/value along with legends. Is there any other way to increase entire chart size?

Comment: @RamAnji: Try the suggestion above.