# Get dynamically the width of the range axis

Tags: java, jfreechart

for layout reasons, i need to know when the width of the range axis changes. 
For example, when the range of the range axis goes from 1000 - 10000 the domain axis is more "squeezed" than with a range from 1 - 10.

i need this width 
.....^
|10000|
...........|
...........|
...........|
...........|
.........1|_________________________________________________
..............1......................................5..........................................10

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117530); possible [*xy problem*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/163188).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, i can get this width with this way:

```
chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getDataArea().getWidth();
```

Comment: [Here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117530#p179592) you ask, "How can i manipulate this width?" Some approaches are examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)  But my main problem now is, to set the width of the data area after the chart is created.