# How to insert a JFreeChart chart in a panel on a separate GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfreechart

I want to put a chart inside a specific panel in a GUI using JFreeChart. I have 2 java files (one with the GUI, and another that creates the graph) and would like , if possible, to keep it this way.

In the main GUI I have a panel called panelGraph:

```
    JPanel panelGraph = new JPanel();
    panelGraph.setBounds(220, 64, 329, 250);
    panelMain.add(panelGraph); //it is inside the main panel
    panelGraph.setLayout(null);
```

And I also have a button that triggers the appearance of the graph:

```
    Button btnGetGraph = new JButton("Draw Graph");
    btnGetGraph.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            XYLineChart_AWT.runGraph("Cenas", "Titulo", "XLABEL", "YLABEL", panelGraph);

        }
    });
    btnGetGraph.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
    btnGetGraph.setBounds(323, 327, 128, 34);
    panelMain.add(btnGetGraph);
```

And as follows, is the java file that creates the graph:

```
  public class XYLineChart_AWT extends JFrame {
  public XYLineChart_AWT( String applicationTitle, String chartTitle, String xLabel, String yLabel, JPanel panel) {

  JFreeChart xylineChart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
     chartTitle ,
     xLabel ,
     yLabel ,
     createDataset() ,
     PlotOrientation.VERTICAL ,
     true , false , false);

  ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel( xylineChart );
  chartPanel.setPreferredSize( panel.getSize() );


  final XYPlot plot = xylineChart.getXYPlot( );
  plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(240, 240, 240));
  XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true,false);
  renderer.setSeriesPaint( 0 , Color.BLACK );
  renderer.setSeriesStroke( 0 , new BasicStroke( 4.0f ) );
  plot.setRenderer( renderer );
  setContentPane(chartPanel);
  panel.add(chartPanel);
  }

private XYDataset createDataset( ){

  final XYSeries seno = new XYSeries ("Sin");
  for(double i=0;i<=1440;i++){
      double temp=Math.sin(i*((2*Math.PI)/640) + Math.PI) + 1;
      seno.add(i/60, temp);
  }


  final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection( );          
  dataset.addSeries(seno);
  return dataset;
}

public static void runGraph(String appTitle, String chartTitle, String xLabel, String yLabel, JPanel panel) {
  XYLineChart_AWT chart = new XYLineChart_AWT(appTitle, chartTitle, xLabel, yLabel, panel);

  chart.pack();
  chart.setVisible(true);
  panel.setVisible(true);

 }
}
```

This creates the graph and puts it into the specified panel (that I send through the method runGraph()).
However, it creates a 2nd JFrame ( I know i made chart.setVisible(true) and I can just put it to false) that I don't want to be created outside of the panel I send.

Is there any way to implement this that does not create that extra jFrame?

P.S.: Another question: the setBackgroundPaint() method changes the back of where the graph is shown. However the parts where the title and legend are don't change. How can I change those parts?

Thank you for your help,

Nhekas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `XYLineChartAWT` constructor to instantiate a `ChartPanel`, make `runGraph()` a factory method that returns a `JFreeChart` for use in your main GUI's `ChartPanel`. Use the chart panel method `setChart()`, which will update your panel automatically. To change the chart panel's default size, override `getPreferredSize()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513).

[image]

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36757609/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(null);
        f.add(chartPanel);
        f.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Draw Graph") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                chartPanel.setChart(
                    new XYLineChartAWT().runGraph("Title", "X", "Y"));
            }
        }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }
}

public class XYLineChartAWT {

    public JFreeChart runGraph(String chartTitle, String xLabel, String yLabel) {
        JFreeChart xylineChart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            chartTitle,
            xLabel,
            yLabel,
            createDataset(),
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true, false, false);
        final XYPlot plot = xylineChart.getXYPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(240, 240, 240));
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, false);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLACK);
        renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(4.0f));
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);
        return xylineChart;
    }

    private XYDataset createDataset() {
        final XYSeries seno = new XYSeries("Sin");
        for (double i = 0; i <= 1440; i++) {
            double temp = Math.sin(i * ((2 * Math.PI) / 640) + Math.PI) + 1;
            seno.add(i / 60, temp);
        }
        final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(seno);
        return dataset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will try this later today and I will come back with a proper reply. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: In order for it to work properly I had do use .setBounds() method on the chartPanel created for the graph. However, for what I read online, this is not the best pratice. I am supposed to use LayoutManagers, right? Which one do you recommend to use? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Nhekas: I agree about avoiding `setBounds()`. The default layout of `JFrame` is `BorderLayout` and the default destination is `CENTER`, implicit in the above example; `GridLayout`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513), also allows the chart to adjust as the frame is resized.

Comment: Ok, I will try that Layout. Another non-related question: when creating the main frame, how should I create it ? 
If i use pack() method, even if I have multiple components, it will start really small. Is it because currently is set as a null (absolute) layout?

Comment: Right; also override `getPreferredSize()` so `pack()` will know how big the panel should be.

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest use Nice Application 1 the Jfree modified jar can download from NiceApplication1.BlogSpot.Com. Go to the blog and Download new Nice Application 1 Home Stupendous, then after extract, the folder go to the dist folder and open the Java Jar Nice Application 1, so you will get a modified jar jfree_NiceApplication1 with a notepad file about how can use that jar.

A pie chart example is available.

After jar only need to type method-

String ao1 = a1.getText();
String ao2 = a2.getText();

DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();

```
    pieDataset.setValue("earn", new Double(ao1));
    pieDataset.setValue("Allbilltotal", new Double(ao2));
```

//Note pieDataset & ch will be your variable.

JFreeChart ch = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("Test", pieDataset, true, true, true);

```
    PiePlot3D p = (PiePlot3D) ch.getPlot();
```

// import org.jfree.chart.Nice_Application_1_JPanel;

```
    Nice_Application_1_JPanel pant = new Nice_Application_1_JPanel(pieDataset);  
    pieDataset = pant.pieDataset;
    pant.PanelApplication1 = jPanel;   
    pant.size = new java.awt.Dimension(200, 200);
    pant.Nice_Application1(ch);
```

StandardChartTheme theme = new StandardChartTheme(ch.toString());

```
theme.setTitlePaint( Color.decode( "#4572a7" ) );
theme.setRangeGridlinePaint( Color.decode("#C0C0C0"));
theme.setPlotBackgroundPaint( Color.blue );
theme.setChartBackgroundPaint( Color.BLACK );
theme.setGridBandPaint( Color.red );
theme.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
theme.setAxisLabelPaint( Color.decode("#666666")  );
```

theme.apply( ch );

---

For line chart also can type the same, the place of the Chart panel type only-
// import org.jfree.chart.Nice_Application_1_JPanel;

```
    Nice_Application_1_JPanel pant = new Nice_Application_1_JPanel(pieDataset);  
    pieDataset = pant.pieDataset;
    pant.PanelApplication1 = jPanel;   
    pant.size = new java.awt.Dimension(200, 200);
    pant.Nice_Application1(ch);
```

---