# How to change the type of the chart after creating it?

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart

I created a graph of xy line chart by this code:

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
        "", // chart title
        "Viscosity @25 C°", // x axis label
        "Tg C°", // y axis label
        dataset, // data
        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
        true, // include legend
        true, // tooltips
        false // urls
);
```

Now after I created it, I want to change the type to `SpiderWebPlot`. How to do this?

I tried to create in chart variable the `spiderWebPlot`, but it din't work.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html) in a [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) and invoke `setChart()` to replace the chart in the panel as the need arises. Complete examples are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36757609/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36764715/230513). To change the chart panel's initial size, override `getPreferredSize()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513).