# Resize JFreeChart.ChartPanel on maximizing screen

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have a JFrame `frame` which contains a `JPanel` panel. I also added a `JFreeChart ChartPanel cp` to the panel. What I did so far is using a `ComponentListener` on my frame `frame` to react on resizing the window.

Here is my code snippet:

```
private void initialize() throws ParseException {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            ChartPanel cp = (ChartPanel)panel.getComponents()[0];
            cp.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight()));
            frame.repaint();
            cp.repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}
    });

    ...
}
```

The `ChartPanel` is resized perfectly when changing the size of the frame. But when I maximize my frame the chart panel won't change it's size! It stays at the same same as it is at the moment before maximizing. Therefore when I "un-maximize" my frame again, the chart panel is maximized and this leads to the problem, that the chart won't fit into the chart panel anymore. All this resize thing seems to be "one step behind"...

Does anyone know this behavior and help how to correct it?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: This is what a LayoutManager does. Why are you reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `ChartPanel.setSize` after `ChartPanel.setPreferredSize` and `JFrame.validate` did the job! See the new code:

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        // frame.repaint();
        ChartPanel cp = (ChartPanel)panel.getComponents()[0];
        cp.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight()));
        cp.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight()));
        // frame.invalidate();
        frame.validate();
        // frame.repaint();
    }
    ...
});
...
```

Comment: Just add your `ChartPanel` to a layout that lets the chart expand, e.g. `GridLayout`; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513).

Comment: did not do the job for me