# Missing points when zoom in jfreechart

Tags: zooming, jfreechart

I have a jfreechart with X symbolAxis. (Jfreechart 1.0.14).
When I use the mouse in order to zoom in, I see only some of the points and not all the points(or sometimes doesn't the point at all - depend how many points are there.)

Can someone please help me with it?
[before zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjUTt.jpg)
[after zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Krn.jpg)

Comment: It look like a layout/scrollpane issue; please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: I tried to create a sample code, but it doesn't reproduce in the sample code, and my code is too complicated to put it here.
When I invert my chart (symbol axis in the Y instead of in the X), and the point are inverted, so the whole chart is rotated in ninety degrees - The chart looks fine.
Any idea is welcome...I am really stuck.

Comment: Don't put a `ChartPanel` in a `JScrollPane` without understanding both; try one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513) instead..

Comment: The bug was jfreechart's, and I fixed it by overriding jfreecharts functions as following:[link]http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115655