# JFree pie chart section label goes outside pie section

Tags: jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart to create pie charts. I want to set a label inside pie section.But some part of label goes out side of pie section. Please can any one help me? I want to set this label inside the section only.

```
plot.setLabelFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
plot.setNoDataMessage("No data available");
plot.setCircular(true);
plot.setLabelPaint(Color.DARK_GRAY);
plot.setSimpleLabels(true);
```

Comment: Have you tried [enlarging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513) the enclosing panel or image bounds?

Comment: Yes I tried but as image gets enlarged the label also gets near to the section edge and some part gets out of the section.
I checked by reducing font size but font should be too small.
which is not readable.

Comment: I usually shorten the label and put the extra text in a tooltip.

Comment: I am rendering the chart as an image. So tool tip will not work fro me.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the above?