# Read data from CSV file into ArrayList and display in XY Chart

Tags: java, arraylist, charts, jfreechart

I would like to display a temperature curve over time. I have now read a file, which is CSV-similar, that let me know the time and the temperature indicated. Now I want to use JFreeChart to display an XY graph from the values.
The original data of the file looks as follows:

```
utc,local,celsius
2017-07-12T07:02:53+00:00,2017-07-12T09:02:53+02:00,26.25
2017-07-12T08:02:54+00:00,2017-07-12T10:02:54+02:00,26.08
2017-07-12T09:02:55+00:00,2017-07-12T11:02:55+02:00,25.78
2017-07-12T10:02:56+00:00,2017-07-12T12:02:56+02:00,25.96
2017-07-12T10:51:02+00:00,2017-07-12T12:51:02+02:00,26.14
2017-07-12T10:51:02+00:00,2017-07-12T12:51:02+02:00,26.14
```

The output of time & temperature values (I have separated from the original file) looks like:

```
09:02:53,26.25
10:02:54,26.08
11:02:55,25.78
12:02:56,25.96
12:51:02,26.14
12:51:02,26.14
```

EDIT:
Now I have inserted a DateTimeFormatter in the example from Trashgod:
It looks like:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        ApplicationFrame frame = new ApplicationFrame("CSVTest");
        Test test = new Test();
        frame.add(test.createChart("Temperature profile"));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);;
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}

private ChartPanel createChart(String chartTitle) {
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(chartTitle,
        "Time", "Temperature", createDataset(), true, true, false);
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    DateAxis domain = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
    domain.setDateFormatOverride(DateFormat.getDateInstance());
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
    return chartPanel;
}


    private XYDataset createDataset() {
    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Temperature");
    TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection(series);
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("TestCSV.csv");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
        String line;
        br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] split = line.split(",");

           System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(split[1]).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)  + "," +split[2]);
           ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(),LocalTime.parse(split[0]), ZoneId.systemDefault());
           String s = ZonedDateTime.parse(split[0]).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME);

           Second second =  new Second(Date.from(zdt.toInstant()));
           series.add(second, Double.valueOf(split[1]));
        }
    } catch (IOException | SeriesException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e);
    }
    return dataset;
}
```

The first line of the "CSV" -like file is still displayed 09:02:53,26.25 
Then I get a DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-07-12T09:02:53+02:00' could not be parsed at index 2

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-07-12T07:02:53+00:00' could not be parsed at index 2
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.time.LocalTime.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.time.LocalTime.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.jfree.chart.demo.Test.createDataset(Test.java:63)
at org.jfree.chart.demo.Test.createChart(Test.java:43)
at org.jfree.chart.demo.Test.lambda$0(Test.java:34)
```

Why can not the rest of the file be read nor displayed?
("System.out.println()" should only serve as a control at the end). The DateTimeFomatter is correct, isn´t it?

With your approach, the time to make locally I come no further & the program can not translate. What did I do wrong? How could it work if the direct output

```
09:02:53,26.25
10:02:54,26.08
11:02:55,25.78
12:02:56,25.96
12:51:02,26.14
12:51:02,26.14
```

is displayed in a chart? I think to split and to transform like I did is okay, isn´t it? Now I have setDateFormatOverride ()  in the code, but the error message, as well as the output remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems are evident:

- You never add anything to `lines`; at a minimum, you'll need something like this:

  ```
  lines.add(line);
  ```
- Instead of `ChartFactory.createXYLineChart()`, consider creating a time series:

  ```
  ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(…)
  ```
- The `XYDataset` returned by `createDataset()` should be a `TimeSeriesCollection` to which you add a [`TimeSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html).
- In `createDataset()`, iterate though `lines`, parse the data fields, and add the values to the `TimeSeries`.
- The time values given are most closely modeled by `LocalTime`, but `TimeSeries` expects to `add()` coordinates defined by a `RegularTimePeriod` and a `double`; see [*Legacy Date-Time Code*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/legacy.html) concerning the conversion shown below.
- Note that `TimeSeries` throws `SeriesException` for duplicate domain values; as a result, only three of the four lines int eh sample input air charted.
- Instead of *replacing* the factory supplied `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`, get a reference to it for later modification.
- Alter the chart's size using one of the approaches shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513).
- Avoid extending top-level containers line `ApplicationFrame`.
- Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Use a [*try-with-resources statement*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.
- As your [actual data](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45166365/7) contains [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC) dates, [`ZonedDateTime.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) can be used directly; use [`setDateFormatOverride()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html#setDateFormatOverride-java.text.DateFormat-) to format the date axis labels; the example below specifies a UTC time zone in ISO 8601 format for easy comparison; comment out the call to `setDateFormatOverride()` to see the times in your local time zone.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.general.SeriesException;
import org.jfree.data.time.Second;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45173688/230513 */
public class CSVTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            ApplicationFrame frame = new ApplicationFrame("CSVTest");
            CSVTest test = new CSVTest();
            frame.add(test.createChart("Temperature profile"));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);;
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private ChartPanel createChart(String chartTitle) {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(chartTitle,
            "Time", "Temperature", createDataset(), true, true, false);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer r = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        r.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
        DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ssX");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        axis.setDateFormatOverride(df);
        return chartPanel;
    }

    private XYDataset createDataset() {
        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Temperature");
        TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection(series);
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("temp.csv");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] s = line.split(",");
                ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(s[0]);
                Second second = new Second(Date.from(zdt.toInstant()));
                series.add(second, Double.valueOf(s[2]));
            }
        } catch (IOException | SeriesException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }
        return dataset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But now the problem is the split. The "CSV" similar file was split, and in the end it looks like "Time and Temperature" originally it looks like this: 
2017-07-12T07:02:53+00:00,2017-07-12T09:02:53+02:00,26.25
With your approach, the time to make locally I come no further & the program can not translate. What make I wrong?
How could it work if the direct output:
 
11:02:55,25.78
12:02:56,25.96
Is displayed in a chart? I think to split and to transform like I did is okay, isn´t it?

Comment: It looks like you'll need a `DateTimeFormatter`; the tutorial cited has a section on parsing. Now that you have a working example, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45166365/edit) your question to include a [mcve] that shows the _actual_ data and your revised approach.

Comment: I have the question revised and now an EDIT added with the appropriate error messages

Comment: I'm still seeing the old data; please include the actual data.

Comment: Are you still seeing the actual data?

Comment: Your string array, `split`, has two components with indexes 0 and 1; try parsing `split[0]`.

Comment: I´ve tried parsing split[0], but it doesn´t work. Is series.add() okay?

Comment: My example produces the chart shown with the data you originally posted. Please edit your question to include a few representative lines of the _actual_ data you want to parse; a single line is not enough. The single line you posted looks like two offset date-times and a value. Use `OffsetDateTime` to parse either substring; they both appear to represent the same `Instant`.

Comment: Need I really still OffsetDateTime if I have already separated the data required & only want to display this?

Comment: Use `ZonedDateTime`; otherwise you lose crucial information; if needed, use `setDateFormatOverride()` to format the date as shown above.

Comment: Now I have setDateFormatOverride ()  in the code, but the error message, as well as the output remain the same. Any idea why? I don´t understand that there are no problems with the first line (output is okay), but then the java.time.format.DateTimeParseException.

Comment: Your code does not match mine; see [revision 5](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45173688/revisions).

Comment: oh, okay. Now I´ve tried and it works. Thanks! When you use setDateFormatOverride(df.getTimeInstance()), the output time is shown