# How to convert Java's date strings/objects into JFreeChart's Date format?

Tags: java, datetime, jfreechart, date-format, java-time

I'm creating a candlestick chart using the JFreeChart library. I need to pass time values into OHLCSeries, but it only accepts its own time values

I'm going to pass this class https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/Hour.html

And this constructor: Hour(int hour, int day, int month, int year)

The data which I get from the API originally looks like this: 2021-03-02T16:00:00.000Z

My question: how to convert this date string/Java time formats into JFreeChart's Date format? I can only think about some complicated converting into Java types + returning each value separately, or using regexes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) the date-time string into **[`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)** and then get `java.util.Date` object from this instant. Using this `java.util.Date` object, you can create an instance of [**`Hour`**](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/Hour.html#Hour-java.util.Date-).

```
String strDateTime = "2021-03-02T16:00:00.000Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse(strDateTime);
Hour hour = new Hour(Date.from(instant)));
```

Comment: A similar approach with `ZonedDateTime` is used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45173688/230513).