# JFreeChart alternate background color

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart, linechart

I'm trying to set two colors that need to be switched at every vertical tick label as background of a JFreeChart linechart.

I want the line chart to appear as the image in this link, where two different light grays alternate as background:

[image]

How can I achieve so in JFreeChart?

P.S. I've seen that there is `plot.setRangeTickBandPaint(new Color(200, 200, 100, 100))` method for `XYPlot` plot type, used in `ScatterPlot4` in JFreeChart's demo jar, however, this method does not exist in the line chart plot type.

Comment: Why not `createTimeSeriesChart`?

Comment: Hi trashgod, on the X axis I have custom tick labels dinamically created based on the current week, so that the plot shows week numbers (1 to 53) 1 year backwards from today. On the Y axis, on the other hand, I cannot put symbols since it is a "value" axis, with U.o.M. tons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from this *time series* [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66713994/230513) and using [`setRangeTickBandPaint()`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#setRangeTickBandPaint(java.awt.Paint)), I get the result pictured below:

[image]

In particular, I used

- Contrasting colors for the background and bands:

  ```
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(0xF0F0F0));
    plot.setRangeTickBandPaint(new Color(0xE0E0E0));
  ```
- A suitable `DateFormat` on the domain:

  ```
    domain.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM"));
  ```
- A fixed `TickUnit` on the range:

  ```
    NumberAxis range = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    range.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(5));
  ```
- `DateTickMarkPosition.MIDDLE` to center the tick labels:

  ```
    domain.setTickMarkPosition(DateTickMarkPosition.MIDDLE);
  ```

As an aside, there is no *line chart* plot type. Instead, contrast the source of your chosen [`ChartFactory`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html) with that of a typical *time series*.