# JFreeChart - TimeSeries with respect to TimeZone

Tags: java, jfreechart

Good day, dear colleagues.

I have data with UTC datetime.
While creating the chart, I'd like to convert time to Local time with respecting the timezone set on host machine. Is there a way to do this for TimeSeries?

```
private XYDataset createDataset(Set<Parameters> parameters) {
        var s1 = new TimeSeries("Series1 title");
        for (Parameters p : parameters) {
            s1.addOrUpdate(new Second(p.getDatetime()), p.getTVol()); // <-- p.getDateTime() returns java.util.Date in UTC
        }
        var dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(s1);
        return dataset;
    }
```

Comment: What type does `p.getDateTime()` return? A `String`, or a `Date` or an `OffsetDateTime` or maybe even a `ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: Hi, this is java.util.Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've observed, your chosen [`Second`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/Second.html) constructor accepts a `java.util.Date` that reflects an instant in coordinated universal time (UTC). An alternative to this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68363015/230513) is to defer the conversion from UTC to local time until the value is displayed in the view. As your time series chart likely uses a `DateAxis` for the domain, you will find that local times are displayed by default; use [`setDateFormatOverride()`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html#setDateFormatOverride(java.text.DateFormat)) to change the default display. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45173688/230513), the axis is conditioned to display UTC:

```
DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ssX");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
axis.setDateFormatOverride(df);
```

For comparison, hover over a data point to see the tooltip, which displays the corresponding time in the host platform's local time. Additional examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjfreechart%5D%20DateAxis%20setDateFormatOverride).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I closed the issue by the following trick:

```
private Date convertUtcToLocalDateTime(Date date) {
        var dtfUtc = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormat);
        dtfUtc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("0"));
        var dtfLocal = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormat);
        try {
            return dtfUtc.parse(dtfLocal.format(date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new Date();
        }
    }
```

If someone could propose better solution - I'd be grateful