# JFreeChart CategoryDataset - Axis refresh/repaint problems

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I'm having issues with refreshing/repainting a BarChart after setting a zero value of a CategoryDataset to a very large number.

```
private class Test
    extends ApplicationFrame {

    private DefaultCategoryDataset set;

    public Test(
        String newTitle) {
        super(newTitle);
        set = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        set.addValue(0, "Test", "1");
        JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                "Test",
                "Category",
                "Score",
                set,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,
                true,
                false);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(barChart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(560, 367));
        mainPanel.add(chartPanel);

        JButton b = new JButton();

        createDataset();
        b.addActionListener(e -> {
            set.setValue(Integer.MAX_VALUE, "Test", "1");
        });
        mainPanel.add(b);
        setContentPane(mainPanel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

Here is the chart with a zero value.

[image]

Setting the value to a very large number.

[image]

Clicking inside the chart.

[image]

How can the chart be properly refreshed? I've tried to repaint the ChartPanel, but it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). In addition, override `getPreferredSize()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513), to establish the chart's initial size. In the variation below, note how repeated clicks on the <kbd>Clear</kbd>, <kbd>Zero</kbd> and <kbd>Update</kbd> buttons leave the chart itself unchanged, while updating the dataset, plot, range axis and legend.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/50854965/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private final DefaultCategoryDataset set = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    private int i;

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        set.addValue(0, "Test", "1");
        JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
            "Test", "Category", "Score", set,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(new ChartPanel(barChart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(567, 345);
            }
        });
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Clear") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                set.clear();
                i = 0;
            }
        }));
        p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Zero") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                set.setValue(0, "Test", "1");
                i = 0;
            }
        }));
        p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Update") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                set.setValue(i += 10, "Test", "1");
            }
        }));
        mainPanel.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.add(mainPanel);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Apperently, this does not solve my problem. Change your "Update" mechanism to a larger integer, e.g. Integer.MAX_VALUE instead of adding a small number like 10. The problem only appears if updating a zero value to a very large number.

Comment: I see integer overflow but no anomaly if I initialize the `DefaultCategoryDataset` explicitly at the outset.

Comment: The integer overflow, of course, happens if you add Integer.MAX_VALUE twice. So, here are the steps to reproduce: 1. Start Application 2. "update" -> Result: Y-Axis is shifted to the left, one cannot read the tick-labels. You can set it back to zero (using your "zero"-button, not the "clear"-button) and update again -> same thing happens.

Comment: I see it, now; I don't know why it happens; `set.addValue(1, "Test", "1")` in `display()` may suggest a workaround for your use case.