# Why are these XYItemRenderer methods missing despite importing the right module?

Tags: java, jfreechart, linechart

I am trying to apply the solution found at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458402/jfreechart-line-chart-with-text-at-each-point/14459322#14459322), but when I try to run it in IntelliJ, a couple of the `XYItemRenderer` methods like `setBaseItemLabelGenerator`, `setBaseItemLabelPaint`, `setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition`, etc are not found. I know I imported the right class because the declaration of the renderer is without issue. What else could I be missing that is causing the issue? My modules are managed using Maven and I am using JFreeChart 1.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [example cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458402/jfreechart-line-chart-with-text-at-each-point/14459322#14459322) dates to 2013, when JFreeChart version 1.0.17 was extant. As noted [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart#migration-from-jfreechart-10x) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58887924/230513), beginning with version 1.5.0, "many methods `getBaseXXX()` / `setBaseXXX()` have been renamed `setDefaultXXX()` / `getDefaultXXX()`". For reference, version 1.5.3 is the current release. More with regard to modules in the development release may be found [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/issues/219).