# JFeeChart RingChart remove all margins

Tags: jfreechart

trying to export a RingChart as png, I don't use title or legend, just the chart, still I have white space on the top and bottom:

creating via factory:

```
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createRingChart(
            null, 
            dataset, 
            false,
            false,
            false
    );
```

the following didn't help:

```
chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(0, 0, 0, 0));

RingPlot plot = (RingPlot) chart.getPlot();

plot.setInsets(new RectangleInsets(0, 0, 0, 0.0));
```

I need the chart to be without any margins for the exported image, any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Java2D or Swing? You might be able to optimize the chart's aspect ratio using one of the approaches shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513).

Comment: thanks @trashgod, Java2D (just need the chart image file), I will look into it

Comment: As I recall, the ring resizes to fill the narrowest dimension.