# How make JFreeChart nicely resizable?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jfreechart, sizing

I wonder if it's possible to draw nicely some charts using `JFreeChart` & `ChartPanel`. When I increase window size I want the chart to fill-up the new space, using a `GridBayLayout`. But the text labels are streched also and becomes really ugly.

Here is the default size of a given charts:
[image: default jfreechart rendering]

And here is what it looks like when I maximize the window:
[image: maximized jfreechart rendering ugly]

As you can see, the text is badly streched. This is not the behavior of other swing components (like the JLabel of the top-text).

**How can I configure my charts/plots to tell the plot to fill-up all new space, but keep legends, axis and any other elements fixed-size ?**

Comment: Among the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513), try `GridLayout`. If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: Thanks,
The use of the full `ChartPanel` constructor by specifying much higher values for `maximumDrawWidth` and `maximumDrawHeight` fixed the rendering issue.

Comment: I used 2560x1440. I'm using jfreechart library in old version, and the default values was 1024x768. I see the latest version has default values of 2048x1536.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513), the use of the full `ChartPanel` constructor, specifying much higher values for `maximumDrawWidth` and `maximumDrawHeight` parameters, fixed the rendering issue.

I used 2560x1440 instead of 1024x768 (since I'm using jfreechart library in old version). In the latest release, default values are now 2048x1536, and should also be sufficient excepted for full-screen graphs displayed on 4K+ screens.