# How to set a margin on a ValueAxis with auto-calculate disabled?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart for displaying charts in PDF with Apache PdfBox.

My problem is this: I have a Scatter Plot Chart (image attached) that has fixed lower and upper bound, so auto-calculate is not an option. The chart displays a blue dot with the result. However, if the value of dot is 0 or 2 (edge values), the dot is cut out, so I need to set up a margin in this case. I tried with `xAxis.setUpperMargin`, but with no luck.

This is part of the code:

```
NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getDomainAxis();
double tickSize = maxValue > 10 ? 1 : 0.5;
xAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(tickSize));
xAxis.setRange(1, maxValue);
```

[image: Chart Image]

Comment: Why not pad the range, e.g. `setRange(1, maxValue + margin)`?

Comment: @trashgod So, I was looking for solution for two day, made all combinations on axis, and failed, and it was this simple. This helped, if you could post it as answer, I would accept it, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have observed, a "[margin](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setUpperMargin-double-) is added only when the axis range is auto-calculated—if you set the axis range manually, the margin is ignored." Alternatively, you can add a suitable margin when manually setting the range. Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8056418/230513), the following change to `adjustAxis()` adds a 10% margin to each end of each axis, producing the result shown.

```
axis.setRange(-1.1, 1.1);
```

[image: scatter plot with margin]